# Run "clean" all dependent SBT subprojects

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

I have an SBT project, specifically a Play Framework 2.1 project, that has a number of subprojects specified in the configuration. The dependencies seem to work fine when compiling, but "clean" only seems to clean the currently selected project, not including its dependencies. Is there any way to clean both the selected project and its dependent subprojects?

Comment: I wouldn't expect clean to clean all dependencies. You might want an aggregate? (just google sbt aggregates)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your main project aggregates subjects, like this:

```
lazy val root = Project("name", file("."))
    .aggregate(module1, module2, macros)
```

then any command called on this root project will be executed for all subprojects. If you call `inspect clean` command in your sbt session, you'll see, under Related section all subprojects which relates on this clean

*On the side note in the comment*

`aggregate` and `dependsOn` are different command for different purposes. The purpose of **aggregation** is in running commands called on the root project. In my example by calling `test` command on my root project, this command will be executed also for `module1` `module2` and `macros`. If you want to turn off such behaviour with the following setting:

```
aggregate in test := false
```

Aggregated project are independent on the code in them. It's usually used on the root project, nfor example not to call `test` on each project, but to call it on root. Remeber that in case of aggregation commands will be executed in parallel.

And **dependsOn** means that your project will depend on the code from other project. And in this case SBT will execute command sequentialy, in order to `compile` your root project, which `dependsOn` some modules, it should compile those modules at first step, the the root project.

Comment: On a side note, if I use .aggregate, do I still need .dependsOn? When I replaced dependsOn with aggregate, I got some compiler errors in the aggregating project, and it looked like they were all getting compiled in parallel.

Comment: @BenDilts i've added some explanation to your side note